# jQuery Impromptu for WP

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am looking for a plugin like [jQuery Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/) for Wordpress, a plugin which will let me display a overlaid "tour" on the home page.

I searched google quite a bit to no avail and i find Impromptu to be difficult to embed as a standalone for my skills.

Dose anyone know of a Wordpress solution?

Answer:

After following more info from @mccanf i found [this](http://www.designfloat.com/blog/2012/09/10/jquery-website-tour-plugins/) nice jQuery collection page of tour plugins. i was just not looking for the right words i guess.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a WP plugin?

Comment: Because i find that jQuery plugin hard to install..i am looking for a simple interface with Wordpress which not includes to much coding..

Comment: [jQuery Website Tour Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-website-tour-for-wordpress/335968). You have to pay for it. There is a demo site to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can always simply embed a `script` tag into your wordpress pages using the `wp_enqueue_script()` tag, or if you need this library for all of your wordpress pages you can include it within your header.php file.  See this [Wordpress tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript) on how to do it.

Comment: I know how to embed a script file i just dont really know how to instal that plugin in terms of coding it..its too tough for my knowledge in jQuery.